# How do i create a fixed sidebar and a scrollable main content?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, sidebar

In my react, i'm using **simple-flexbox** for my grid. When i add **position: fixed** to my sidebar component, my main component overlaps with the sidebar. Kindly help me out on how i can go about solving this problem.

```
<Row className={css(styles.container)}>
           // My sidebar component
          <SidebarComponent/>
            
           // // My main component which has a header as well
          <Column flexGrow={1} className={css(styles.mainBlock)}>
            <HeaderComponent title={selectedItem} />

            <div className={css(styles.content)}>
              <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={ContentComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsComponents} />
              <Route exact path="/analytics" component={AnalyticsComponent} />
            </div>
          </Column>

</Row>
```

Here is my visual
[image]

Comment: You can add a margin-left or padding-left to your main content that is the same size as the width of your sidebar. This will prevent the overlap

Comment: With position:fixed, you will need to set the width of sidebar(for example 200px). For the main content section, you can then set the width: calc(100vw - 200px); left: 200px;

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your sidebar has a class called sidebarContainer or so, you can use this CSS

```
.sidebarContainer {
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.mainBlock {
    width: calc(100vw - 200px);
    left: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way...
in my case, it's working.

```js
  const ReactComponent = () => {
      const { collapseSidebar, collapsed } = useProSidebar();

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Sidebar
        style={{
          position: 'fixed',
          width: collapsed ? 80 : 250,
          height: '100%',
        }}>

      </Sidebar>
      <main></main>
     </div>
)}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some more details do not post code only answers